# Microservices: All operations of Rest API in single deployable or each operation as independently deployable

Tags: rest, microservices

If I create a RESTful API named CustomerManagement with several operations in it like Create, Update, Retrieve customer etc.

Each operation is considered a business functionality. Backend is a monolith(Provides different SOAP interfaces(WSDLs) for the above operations).

So, as per microservices design principles, should we be creating an independently deployable image (independently versioned as well) for each operation or can the whole Rest API be bundled in a single image?

Comment: please elaborate why you think this should be deployed independently?

Comment: @nitgeek you can deploy the whole API, but sometimes if you need extra flexibility or ability to change moving parts you can split the domain into smaller parts, so it's really depends on your goals.

Answer (score 0):

> If I create a RESTful API named CustomerManagement with several operations in it like Create, Update, Retrieve customer etc

As per REST principles, APIs are designed as resources. A resource represents a domain entity. In your case, the customer is the domain entity. Hence, your REST API should be called 'customers'. The API will look something like /api/v1/customers. You can implement Http operations on this API as needed.

Now to answer your question, all operations belonging to an API should be part of the same application. Splitting it up into different apps or multiple deployments does not make sense - not only will it lead to code duplication, management of each deployment will be an overhead.

I suggest you read about REST principles. This article is good for beginners - https://developer.ibm.com/technologies/web-development/articles/ws-restful

Comment: Thanks, but I am aware of Rest principles, the question is in context of microservices principles.